# Angular date picker with custom range buttons

Tags: angular

I need to implement UI component for angular app with design something like that.
Could you advice some component which could be quickly customized to what I need?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [daterangepicker](https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker) which can solve your main purpose.

This is the live [example](https://demo.improvely.com/reports/webshop/ads?imt=1&utm_campaign=Date%20Range%20Picker&utm_source=Site%20Ads&utm_medium=Banner&utm_content=GitHub%20Demo%20Image) for that